# Use of unnest_tokens() within function in R results in error

Tags: r, unnest

I want to used the unnest_tokens function from tidytext in another function.

Since the column names in the data frame i pass may be different every time, i try to use [[x]] to adress the columns, i have successfully used this in another function, but here it does not work.

This is the code i use:

```
f1 <- function(df) {
  df2 <- df %>%
    unnest_tokens(df[[3]], df[[2]])
  return(df2)
}

data <- structure(list(Id = 1, Description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

result <- f1(data)
```

When executing this i get

```
Fehler während wrapup: Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `unnest_tokens` is the `output` column name. It can be any column name.  So, we can just call it as 'word' and the third argument is the input column name.  Here it is 'Description'.

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, Description)
```

---

One way to do this in a function is pass a column name as argument.  With `tidyverse`, the option is to use curly-curly operator (`{{}}` - if we only want to pass unquoted argument) or another option is convert to `sym`bol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`) - advantage is that it can take both quoted or unquoted column name

```
f1 <- function(dat, nm) {
         dat %>%
           unnest_tokens(word, !! ensym(nm))
 }

out1 <- f1(data, Description)
out2 <- f1(data, 'Description')
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE

out1
#   Id  word
#1    1 lorem
#1.1  1 ipsum
#1.2  1 dolor
#1.3  1   sit
#1.4  1  amet
```

---

If it should be based on column position and it is fixed, then the function can take only the  data object

```
f2 <- function(dat) {
         dat %>%
            unnest_tokens(word, !! rlang::sym(names(dat)[2]))
  }

out3 <- f2(data)
identical(out1, out3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass column name that you want to unnest as an argument to the function and use `.data` to refer it in the function.

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

f1 <- function(df, col) {
  df %>% unnest_tokens(word, .data[[col]])
}

f1(data, 'Description')

#    Id  word
#1    1 lorem
#1.1  1 ipsum
#1.2  1 dolor
#1.3  1   sit
#1.4  1  amet
```